# ClassNotFoundException at first sample code of GridGain

Tags: gridgain

I set up GridGain 6.0.2 and started a node in Windows 7. When i want to run the first example at this [documentation](http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Getting+Started) i get a ClassNotFoundException for the class which has main method. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be GridGain issue, since your IDE cannot see the very class you are trying to run. What kind of IDE are you using?

I would recommend clearing IDE caches, restarting IDE, and rebuilding project.

Comment: I dont think it is an IDE based problem because i compiled my code with maven 3 and I ran "java packageName.GgUtil" command with classpath params. It says "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packageName.GgUtil$1" on the node i started by double clicking "ggstart.bat". Is it wrong to expect GridGain deploy "GridUtil$1" class to nodes by "Zero Deployment" ?